# How to stop infinitely calling AngularJS function from ng-if block?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, infinite-loop

A JS function is being called infinite times from HTML ng-if, and causing errors.

In my HTML, I have the line

`<div ng-if="isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)">`
which calls an angular function below:

```
$scope.isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet = (variant) => {
            if (variant.productCategory.productGroup === 'CANVAS_PRINTS') {
                const featureFlagName = 'MULTICOLOR_CANVAS';
                var featureFlagSet = false;
                return resourceExec({
                    resource: Features.getFeature({featureName: featureFlagName}),
                    success: (response) => {
                        if (response && response.name === featureFlagName && response.enabled) {
                            featureFlagSet = true;
                        }
                    },
                    failure: (fail) => {
                        featureFlagSet = false;
                    }
                });
                let storeTagSet = $scope.store.tags.indexOf("multicolorcanvas") != -1;
                return storeTagSet || featureFlagSet;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

which should only be checked once during initialization, and then once anytime a change occurs on the page. However, in my case, when an initial change is made to the page (product added), the above function gets called infinite amount of times, producing the error below infinite times:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: 
[[{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":{}}, 
{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":{}}], 
[{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}, 
{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."},{"msg":"isCanvasAndFeatureFlagOrStoreTagSet(variant)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}]]
```

How do I keep this function from being called infinite times like so?

Comment: First weird thing I noticed, you have two returns in your first if branch, one of which is unreachable. Next, if you have a function that is called from a template that does a lot of work, it should be caching its return value, it seems like you are making an expensive call from a template function

Comment: @JuanMendes By caching return value, do you mean I should just call this function in the controller, and the function should just set a $scope.boolean value instead of returning it, and access that boolean via scope variable in HTML?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. Caching is hard so you have to figure out how/when to invalidate the cache. One thing is for sure though, you can't call expensive functions  from templates. What I typically do is not call a function from a template,  but have a function that is called when the component is created that sets a property that is used from the template and the template has to be smart enough to show a loading indicator (and a potential error message)